# NumPy элементы массива

Tags: python, numpy

У меня есть массив NumPY
c = np.array([])

Как мне сделать , чтобы в этот массив добавлялись элементы , которые вводит пользователь .
Тип так выглядит ввод в обычный массив
a = []
for i in range(0,10):
    a.append(int(input())
А как он будет в NumPY?

Comment: 1) `ввод в обычный массив` не массив, а список. 2) можно еще проще: `a = [int(input()) for i in range(10)]` 3) У numpy именно массив, а значит задача добавления элементов усложнится -- нельзя просто так создавать пустой массив,  т.к. задача добавления элемента в массив -- это пересоздание нового массива большего размера и добавления в него всех элементов старого. Поэтому, для начала создайте пустой массив с указанным размером, а в цикле через индексы укажите значения

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например:

- Создаете пустой массив длины **N**
- В цикле вызываете **N**-раз `input()`
- По индексу указываете значение в массив

Код:

```
import numpy as np

N = 10

items = np.array([None] * N)
print(items)
# [None None None None None None None None None None]

for i in range(N):
    items[i] = int(input())

print(items)
# [1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 6 7]
```